# WPF Databinding from custom property not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm new to WPF Data binding and can't figure it how to update the property from my viewmodel

I have a class named Patient

```
public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
public string MiddleName { get; set; } = "";
public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
```

updates to the patient class is working

```
private Data.Patient patient;
public Data.Patient Patient
{
     get { return patient; }
     set
     {
          patient = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("Patient");
     }
}
```

a property on my viewmodel which is not updated by the patient class

```
public string FullName
{
     get { return Patient.LastName + " " + Patient.FirstName + " " + Patient.MiddleName; }
}
```

I'm trying to update the TextBlock Text property

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" FontSize="14.667" />
```

how to apply the updates from the Class to my FullName property? Updates are applied when I rerun the application.

Many Thanks

Comment: maybe you should read some article like this one - http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/05/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-one.html The problem here is that you don't notify the UI that FullName has changed. What I recommend you to do is to create a backing field to your name properties (FirstName, LastName...) and in the setter, after assigning the value to the backing field, call NotifyPropertyChanged("FullName")

Comment: okay thanks @NValchev, i'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're not notifying UI that `Fullname` property has changed. Technically it has not changed, but it is dependent on some other property.

The simplest solution here is to raise NotifyProperty event for all properties. You won't have to write plenty of code for it, just pass `null` in `NotifyPropertyChanged();`

```
private Data.Patient patient;

public Data.Patient Patient
{
     get { return patient; }
     set
     {
          patient = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged(null); //informs view that all properties updated
     }
}
```

It will tell your model that all properties have been updated.

[MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx)

> The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object
>   have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name
>   in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.

Answer (score 0):

Change your binding from `Text="{Binding FullName}"` to `Text="{Binding FullName, Mode="OneWay", UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"` that should trigger the PropertyChanged-Event.

Answer (score 0):

Like the `Patient` property with the `NotifyPropertyChanged(...)`, you have to inform the, when the property Fullname has changed. To do that, call  `NotifyPropertyChanged("FullName")` in the setters of the three properties: FirstName, MiddleName and LastName.

Also consider, that NotifyPropertyChanged could be null and use therefore:

```
if (NotifyPropertyChanged != null)
    NotifyPropertyChanged("FullName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to make it work. I added the property to my class so any changes to the class will be notify the UI, still it's not working the way I want.
But I found a solution.

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14.667">
     <TextBlock.Text>
          <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} {1} {2}">
               <Binding Path="Patient.LastName" />
               <Binding Path="Patient.FirstName"/>
               <Binding Path="Patient.MiddleName"/>
          </MultiBinding>
     </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Thanks for the help.